# Is intermediate IO in Bigquery queries charged?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

I have a fairly complex Bigquery query and it seems to cost more than I expect. It has 97 intermediate stages... are those charged?

Answer (score 1):

You can get the value of how much data will be scanned (and therefore charged) by your query using the `--dry-run` switch from the CLI or by looking at the right end of the UI section where you run and set up your query.

BigQuery pricing model is per byte read. For my understanding, at the moment, if you reference a table in multiple CTE you will get charged one. But this might depend on how the query is written.

The best practice is always using the `--dry-run` feature which is very accurate.